# Show custom object in related list under page layout

Tags: salesforce

I have been trying this whole day but cant figure out... I have custom object called Dev which has many to many relationship with Accounts... I want this object Dev to show under related list of page layout of account... But it is not showing there how can i add that to related list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a lookup relation from Account to Dev and also a lookup from Dev to Account (creating your many-to-many), then this will work fine.

Try re-creating your lookup relationship from Account to Dev. Then make sure that you add the related list and add to the page layouts in steps 5 & 6:

- Step 5. Add reference field to Page Layouts (Yes to All)
- Step 6. Add custom related lists (Yes)

That's all you need. If, however, your many-to-many relationship is unique or otherwise configured differently (with a junction table, for example) then the above may not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

We always tend to use joining objects for these relationships, obviously you can show the list of joining objects as a related list, and you could display other fields from the dev object by use of formulae.

One thing we've tended to do is create an inline VF page which can then show all of the objects related to the current record.